# Removing all characters from string which are not letters and changing every first letter of a word to capital letter

Tags: c, string, pointers

I need help with my program in C. My task is too remove all characters which are not letters and change every first letter of a word to capital letter and return the number of deleted non-letters, for example `"i love programming!"` to `"ILoveProgramming"`, it should prop return `3` (number of deleted non letters) . I cannot use the `<ctype.h>`, `<stdlib.h> or` <string.h>`headers,`[]`only to declare array, and I can only use numbers`1`and`0`. Also I can't change the function definition or do anything with that (`int message_compression(char * txt);`). So far I managed to change letters but I have no idea how to remove characters which are not letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int message_compression(char* txt);

int main() {
    char txt[1001];
    char *wt;
    wt = txt;
    puts("Text:");
    fgets(txt, 1001, stdin);
    message_compression(wt);
    int i = 0;
    printf("After change:\n");
    while (*wt != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *wt);
        i++;
        *wt = *(wt + i);
    }
    return 0;
}

int message_compression(char* txt) {
    if (txt == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (*(txt + i) != '\x0') {
        if (i == 0) {
            *(txt + i) = *(txt + i) - ' ';
        }
        if (*(txt + i) == ' ' || *(txt + i) == ',' || *(txt + i) == '.') {
            if (*(txt + i + 1) != ' ' && *(txt + i + 1) != ',' && *(txt + i + 1) != '.') {
                *(txt + i + 1) = *(txt + i + 1) - ' ';
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is easier to read and understand, as well as less to write.

Comment: Secondly I suggest you take a couple of steps back, and restart the program from scratch. This time use *divide and conquer*, where you divide the large and complex original problem into smaller and less complex problems. Do this division until it's not possible any more. Then solve and implement, bit by bit, the small and very simple problems, put them together until you have finally solved the large and complex original problem. And instead of a single function which does everything, use many small and simple functions that are easy to test by themselves.

Comment: Thirdly, instead of moving characters around in a single array, I suggest you *copy* wanted characters to a new array. And remember to copy the string terminator as well (which you don't seem to move correctly in your code).

Comment: Are you allowed to define other functions such as `is_letter()` and `to_capital()` and use them in your implementation of `message_compression()`?

Comment: I think i can use other functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to define other functions such as `is_letter()` and `to_capital()` and use them in your implementation of `message_compression()`, here is pseudo code for a simple solution:

- let `i = 0` the read index, and `j = 0` the write index
- repeat:

  - repeat while character at offset `i` is not a letter:

    - if the character at offset `i` is the null terminator set a null terminator at offset j and return `i - j`
    - otherwise increment `i`
  - store the character `to_capital`(character at offset `i`) at offset `j`
  - increment `i` and `j`
  - repeat while character at offset `i` is a letter:

    - copy the character at offset `i` to offset `j`
    - increment `i` and `j`

Try and code it in C within the constraints imposed for the assignment.

Here is a simplified framework:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_letter(char c) {
    // simple solution for ASCII
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

char to_capital(char c) {
    // simple solution for ASCII
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        return 'A' + (c - 'a');
    else
        return c;
}

int message_compression(char* txt) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (;;) {
        while (!is_letter(txt[i])) {
            if (txt[i] == '\0') {
                txt[j] = '\0';
                return i - j;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        txt[j++] = to_capital(txt[i++]);
        while (is_letter(txt[i])) {
            txt[j++] = txt[i++];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char txt[1001];

    puts("Text:");
    if (fgets(txt, sizeof txt, stdin)) {
        int deleted = message_compression(txt);
        printf("After change: %s\n", txt);
        printf("Characters removed: %d\n", deleted);
    }
    return 0;
}
```